# `stack build` a fresh `yesod init` not store executable into `dist/build`

Tags: cabal, yesod, stackage

When I used `cabal build` I found the `yesod` executable into `dist/build` directory but now, using `stack build` I found this into

```
./.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-3.1/7.10.2/bin/Test02
./.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Test02
./.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Test02/Test02
```

I cannot find the reason (some cabal/stack behavior change, my fault, ...).

I prefer use `dist/build` instead versioned paths to script out my deploy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case of deployments can be handled with the `--copy-bins --local-bin-path somedir` flags, which will have the executables copied to the target directory.